# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on a keyboard action

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a problem: 
You can see that in my dismissKeyboard Function I have got an error.
Can you explain me the error?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDXIa.png]

Comment: The error is in the debug console: wrapping optional value stuff. `textField` seems to be nil. The IBOutlet doesn't seems to be connected to your Xib. Also, don't tag with OS X or Objective-C when it's not related to them!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your **UITextField is nil**.

In line 12 where you have your textfield declared there is a small circle next to the line number. If you have your outlet connected correctly this circle is filled.

If you change to splitt-view (upper right corner - the two circles) you can drag from said circle to the textfield to make the connection.